# PostgreSql как у создаваемого типа данных получить значение поля?

Tags: postgresql

Создаю свой тип данных

**CREATE TYPE student AS
(
"firstName" character varying,
"secondName" character varying,
"age" integer,
"status" character varying
);**

Есть функция change_status(student, old_status, new_status) которая возвращаем student c изменёнными значениями полей

Мне нужно создать функцию которая возвращает поле firstNameиз student

**CREATE FUNCTION student_name (IN "currentStudent" student, IN "secondName" character varying)
RETURNS character varying
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS
BEGIN
RETURN change_status(currentStudent,secondName).firstName;
END;**

Но происходит ошибка syntax error около точки, то есть он не понимает блок .firstName. В oracle я так значение полей получать мог а тут нет. Может кто знает как получить из созданного типа данных значение поля?

Comment: Посмотри тут пример https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html `CREATE FUNCTION price_extension(inventory_item, integer) RETURNS numeric
AS 'SELECT $1.price * $2' LANGUAGE SQL;`

Comment: Похоже, что вокруг вызова ф-ции должны быть скобки, чтобы иметь доступ к полю `Similar syntactic issues apply whenever you select a field from a composite value. For instance, to select just one field from the result of a function that returns a composite value, you'd need to write something like:

SELECT (my_func(...)).field FROM ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы читать поле из возвращаемого функцией объекта, надо вызов функции дополнительно оборачивать в скобки `(getObject(params)).field`

В твоём случае будет

```sql
CREATE  TYPE student AS ( firstName text, secondName text, age integer, status text);


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION change_status (currentStudent student, secondName text) 
  RETURNS student AS
$$
BEGIN
   RETURN (
       SELECT ROW(currentStudent.firstName, secondName, currentStudent.age, currentStudent.status)::student
     );
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE FUNCTION student_name(currentStudent student, secondName text) RETURNS text AS 
$$
BEGIN
 RETURN (
  SELECT (change_status(currentStudent,secondName)).firstName
 );
END 
$$ 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';


select student_name(row('John', 'Smith', 12, 'alive')::student, 'Snow') ;
```

```
John
```

Comment: Большое спасибо